# Generate JSON Format from Date and usage

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, json, asp.net-web-api, poco

I want to create the JSON Response in WEBAPI.  Following is the POCO Format of JSON. I want it into asp.net WEB API .
                  it is too much confusing . Kindly help me . thanks in advance

```
   public class LstDateUsage
       {
           public int carrierId { get; set; }
           public double data { get; set; }
           public string date { get; set; }
           public double minutes { get; set; }
           public double sms { get; set; }
       }

       public class LstWeekUsage
       {
           public int carrierId { get; set; }
           public double data { get; set; }
           public List<LstDateUsage> lstDateUsages { get; set; }
           public double minutes { get; set; }
           public double sms { get; set; }
           public string week { get; set; }
       }

      public class LstMonthUsage
      {
          public int carrierId { get; set; }
          public double data { get; set; }
          public List<LstWeekUsage> lstWeekUsages { get; set; }
          public double minutes { get; set; }
          public string month { get; set; }
          public double sms { get; set; }
      }

      public class LstQuarterUsage
      {
          public int carrierId { get; set; }
          public double data { get; set; }
          public List<LstMonthUsage> lstMonthUsages { get; set; }
          public double minutes { get; set; }
          public string quarter { get; set; }
          public double sms { get; set; }
      }

      public class Year
      {
          public int carrierId { get; set; }
          public double data { get; set; }
          public List<LstQuarterUsage> lstQuarterUsages { get; set; }
          public double minutes { get; set; }
          public double sms { get; set; }
          public string year { get; set; }
      }

      public class RootObject
      {
          public int carrierId { get; set; }
          public List<Year> years { get; set; }
      }
```

For creating the JSON I have sample input data in this format

```
 Date, Type, Usage, Provider
 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000    3   7   2983903
 2015-01-02 00:00:00.000    3   7   3898111
 2015-01-03 00:00:00.000    3   7   1569424
 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000    2   7   4305933
 2015-01-05 00:00:00.000    3   7   3995045
 2015-01-06 00:00:00.000    3   7   2902631
 2015-01-07 00:00:00.000    1   8   3962638
 2015-01-08 00:00:00.000    3   8   731317
 2015-01-09 00:00:00.000    1   7   1769561
 2015-01-10 00:00:00.000    3   8   4333871
 2015-01-11 00:00:00.000    3   7   1940508

 Here 1=SMS,2=Voice,3=Data ,7=A1, 8=A2
 we have to process the output on one-year records.
 So, for 365 days of 3 type will be 1045 records for one provider,
 if we count for two providers then it will be approx 2090 rows in SQL server .
```

Comment: Why not have a single Usage class with a start and end date instead of having all these separate time based classes?

Comment: that I can not change as per requirement I have to use. So can you Proceed with same?